# Get data value from php array with autocomplete jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I try to use the plugin from "devbridge autocomplete" : https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/
I would like to get 3 values from my search.php page (and not just 1).
It works for "value" but not for "data1" and "data2" (result for each = null)

My jQuery code :

```
$('#search-adress').autocomplete({
serviceUrl: 'search.php',
dataType: 'json',
onSelect: function (value,data1,data2) {
        alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data1 + ', ' + data2);
    }
});
```

My search page :

```
$term=$_GET['query'];
$query = mysql_query("select distinct adress,id,city from myadresstable where (adress like '%{$term}%') order by adress limit 10 ");
if (mysql_num_rows($query))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $reply['suggestions'][] = ''.utf8_encode($row['nom_voie']).'';
        $reply['data1'][] = ''.utf8_encode($row['id']).'';
        $reply['data2'][] = ''.utf8_encode($row['city']).'';
    }
 echo json_encode($reply);
}
```

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html

Comment: Mys problem is with the script of devbridge and not jquery-ui

Comment: You should use `json_encode` in your php code: `json_encode($reply);`

Comment: Sorry I forgott to write here but json_encode was present on my source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution :)

The problem was the `PHP` Array. To get some data values with this autocomplete plugin you have to use `array()` :

PHP Code

```
$suggestions = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($query))
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 $mydata1='$row['data1']';
 $mydata2='$row['data2']';
$nom_voie=''.utf8_encode($row['nom_voie']).'';
$suggestions[] = array(
    "value" => $nom_mydata1,
    "data" => $nom_mydata2
);

    }
}
echo json_encode(array('suggestions' => $suggestions));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change a bit the php array this way:

```
$term=$_GET['query'];
$query = mysql_query("select distinct adress,id,city from myadresstable where (adress like '%{$term}%') order by adress limit 10 ");
if (mysql_num_rows($query))
{
   $arr = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
     $reply['suggestions'] = utf8_encode($row['nom_voie']);
     $reply['data'] = utf8_encode($row['id']);
     $reply['value'] = utf8_encode($row['city']);
     $arr[] = $reply;
   }
   echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

And in your jquery code:

```
 $(function(){
 $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: datos,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log(suggestion);
         alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data + ', ' + suggestion.nom_voie);
    }
  });
});
```

#### Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/n6oLLfmc/

- Try selecting "Valdivia" to see the alert

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't works I have an error on the console "TypeError: b is undefined" When I try on fiddle it works but the results are in var [] from jquery code and not php code. An idea ?

Comment: Did you change your php code to match mine...if you look closer, i change the array structure a little bit.